# Trying to assign a new derived object to a base class pointer but it seems to act like nothing happened

Tags: c++

Thanks in advance for the replies.

store() is a function of Backpack class which is holding an array of pointers (Item * items). The arguments sent to store() are correct (tested by printing them out with cout). displayInventory() still prints the previous Item object's members at the end of the function.

```
void store(string & name, float weight, int power, int slot)
        {
            items[slot] = new Weapon(name, weight, power); // Weapon is a derived class of Item
            this->displayInventory();
        }
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Researching vectors now.

Comment: You don't initialize your `items` member correctly. I'd recommend using a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>` instead of a raw (array) pointer. Further you should try to narrow your question to nail your problems. As it is: TL;DR;

Comment: Yeah, I tried to keep it short but give all relevant information. It's hard to ask a question when you don't really know what's wrong in the first place.

Comment: I would recommend that you do some more research about dynamic memory allocation in C++ as you do not seem to grasp how it works. It seems to me perhaps you are trying to run before you have learned to walk.

Comment: @firstcomment Also... I have no idea how to use what you wrote! And thank you for the response. I will try to learn the vector thing again. Last time I looked into it I was completely lost.

Comment: @mathematician1975 I'd recommend the OP should do research on how to avoid direct dynamic management at all, because this is a constant source of programming errors.

Comment: @mathematician Yeah, at some point research doesn't do you a whole lot of good. I've done plenty of reading and I still don't really understand it completely. Stackoverflow has been my only source of help (and amazing help it has been). But, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes but you need to learn what it actually is and how it works to know *why* it causes such problems. I don't think it is a good idea to omit dynamic memory allocation from the learning process.

Comment: @Dex Yes but if you don't know the difference between `delete` and `delete []` then maybe you need to do a bit more reading. Maybe try to concentrate on learning individual areas one at a time rather than the whole thing at once.

Comment: @mathematician1975 I only had one example of dynamically allocating an array in my textbook. I followed it pretty much verbatim and it caused errors. In fact, they never even talked about delete [], it just showed up in an example. Until now, I didn't even realize that there may be a major difference. I'll try to look into it again.

Comment: You can use `new` to allocate memory for one item or many (an array) items. The return value is a pointer in both cases. `int* p = new int[10]` allocates memory for an array of 10 integers - when you call `new` using [] (ie to allocate an array) you must call `delete []` to clear all the memory. When you call `new` to allocate just one object you just use `delete`. I would do some googling and read as many books as you can. Look up terms like memory leak too as one of the aspects in your question indicates potential for memory leaks.

Comment: @mathematician1975 Ok, cool. Thanks for the info. I did some digging and tried some new stuff in my program. And, it failed, haha. Oh well. I'll stop bothering you guys. I'm obviously way in over my head...

Comment: @Dex Don't stop posting here - but if you formulate questions that deal with one thing at a time using a small code fragment that illustrates your problem you will get far better answers than if you post ALL your code that has multiple problems. C++ is not an easy language - persevere with it.

Comment: @mathematician1975 Thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here are a couple of things which might ease your life (and the life of those who will read your code). It would simplify your code. Hence it will make easier to understand and debug:

- Use relevant names for your variables.

Example:

```
void store(string & name, float weight, int power, int slot)
{
  items[slot] = new Weapon(name, weight, power);
  numItems+=1;
  this->getInventory();
}
```

- Use relevant / consistent names for your methods.

Here, it's hard to understand what is the purpose of `getInventory()` because it starts with `get`, yet its return type is`void`. (Maybe you meant `buildInventory()`?)

- You don't need to redefine in your derive class, what is already in the base class.

In particular you don't need to redefine `name`, `weight` and `power` (and their getters) in `Weapon`, since it's already defined in `Item`

- If you don't define any constructor in a class, the compiler will provide a default one without arguments.

It means you can remove the line `Container(){;}`

- Don't reinvent the wheel. You'd better use a `std::vector` rather than trying to handling yourself pointers and arrays.

I'm pretty sure this last advice can by itself fix your issue. In particular, if you use a `vector<Item>`, you won't need to manipulate pointers yourself anymore. It means no more `new` and no more `delete`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointers. It seems that learning how to use vector is the next thing I need to figure out.